# How to append data to a resultset in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, orm, append, resultset, cakephp-3.0

I have a simple json view like this

```
{
  "articles": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Article one",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Article two",
    }
  ]
}
```

This results are paginated, and i'd like to append the pageCount to the results, something like this.

```
{
      "articles": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Article one",
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Article two",
        }
      ],
     "pageCount": 5
    }
```

How can i achieve this? i can't append it directly because it's a resultset object.
Should i be doing this in the view/controller/model?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

### The _serialize key

Given that you are using the `JsonView` and auto-serialization

**[Cookbook > Views > JSON and XML Views > Using Data Views with the Serialize Key](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key)**

you can simply add another variable for the view, and mark it for serialization, like

```
$this->set('articles', $this->paginate());
$this->set('pageCount', $this->request->params['paging'][$this->Articles->alias()]['pageCount']);
$this->set('_serialize', ['articles', 'pageCount']);
```

### Using view templates

If you're not using auto-serialization, but custom view templates

**[Cookbook > Views > JSON and XML Views > Using a Data View with Template Files](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-a-data-view-with-template-files)**

you can make use of the `PaginatorHelper` in your template and add the data when converting to JSON, like

```
$pageCount = $this->Paginator->param('pageCount');
echo json_encode(compact('articles', 'pageCount'));
```